# Proving Group using basic four properties

Tags: group-theory

This should be pretty easy but somehow I'd want to be sure about my thoughts on this:

S is the set of integers and the operation concerned is "addition modulo 5".

The broader question is to prove if it forms a group.

What I'm interested in: what is the identity element?

Comment: Can you describe precisely what is the operation with a mathematical definition ?

As I understand what you say, you take two integers $m,n$ and define $m\oplus n$ as the remainder of $m+n$ by $5$. Clearly you cannot obtain a group, this any multiple of $5$ would be a neutral element, so there is a misunderstanding somewhere...